# How to check if an XBOX console is turned on? (remotely)

Tags: xbox, xbox-one

Is there a way to check the status of the console remotely (by HTTP for example) to see if it's running or not?

We want to write a checker app to see if someone is already playing or not.

Comment: How about you nmap the Xbox to see what services are available on it? nmap -p 1-65535 xbox

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Xbox mobile app you can check to see if your Xbox is on, and you can turn it on through the app,  but ONLY if you are connected to the same network as your Xbox. If you are on different networks you won't be able to check because the app will not be able to connect to the console. I do think being able to check it from a source not on the same network would be neat but it could also lead to privacy breaches and, or data leakage.

Comment: Hi Conner, welcome to StackOverflow!  Read the OP's question a litte more closely.  Roby is looking for a way to check remotely (over HTTP), so they are most likely not on the same network.